"being" with different types of adjectives
I divide adjectives into so called ordinary ones such as: nice, famous, big. Second category is adjectives with "ed ending" or the ones which are the same as the third form of a verb like: well-dressed, crooked, drunk and stolen. I'd like you to explain to me how they work with "being".

He is being famous.

I think 1 is correct and means that only currently he is famous

He is being well-dressed

I think 2 is correct but because the verb ends with "ed" it doesn't mean that he is wearing something nice around now but rather that currently he is in the process of putting on some stylish attire.

He is being drunk

The same applies to 3 because "drunk" is the same as the third form of the verb. It won't mean that he is currently drunk but rather that he is around now in the process of getting something to drink from someone
Does my understanding make sense?

Being is not idiomatic with any of those adjectives. He is being dressed would mean that someone is helping him to put his clothes on.

@KateBunting not idiomatic okay. Yet, I think my first example is similar to this "he is being nice" meaning currently he is either nice or famous not always just now. On the other hand 2 and 3 are totally wrong if we want to say that someone has a certain feature right now. My 2 example would imply that currently clothes are being put on him by someone not that he has them on already. The same apllies to 3. Would you say that's correct and my division of adjectives makes sense?

He is being nice means he is behaving nicely today (suggesting that he doesn't always behave that way).  Fame is not a behaviour, and once someone becomes famous they usually stay famous for some time, so we say He is famous. We don't say He is being well-dressed  - in the context you mean it would have to be He is being dressed in stylish clothes.

@KateBunting 1. It is being clean 2. It is being cleaned. 1 shows that something is currently clean it  suggests it's not clean usually. On the other hand, once the adjective in the form of past participle it changes its meaning and 2 means that something is currently being cleaned by someone not that is already spotless. Do I get the difference right?

No. Re 1 - It is being clean, 2 - It is being cleaned, the first one strongly implies the speaker is Indian. It's not idiomatically valid in mainstream English, so it has nothing to do with whether it's normally clean. The second version means someone is currently cleaning it, but again that doesn't imply anything about how often it's clean, and how often it's dirty. We don't use is being X where X is a "semi-permanent" characteristic, such as married, ten years old, famous

We would only use "being" with adjectives of behavior such as nice and naughty? We wouldn't use it with poor rich and so on right?

Right. We say He is rich, not He is being rich. Or sad, tired, happy,... which are all "states of being" regardless of how long they last. But whereas the implication for the rich person is they were probably rich yesterday (and still will be tomorrow), that's just a pragmatic / logical assumption. He is happy describes an ephemeral (temporary) state, with no particular implications for whether he's normally happy.

This comment simply confirms what others have said, to reinforce the message. I would never use any of the examples in your opening question. I would simply use is, without the word being: He is famous; He is well-dressed; He is drunk.

This question is similar to: Can the verb "be' be a dynamic verb?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Edit
Your second category is called
participial adjectives.  The type described consists of past participles acting as adjectives.  Some of these end with 'ed'; some don’t (like 'drunk').
(Another type of participial adjectives consists of present participles.)
I add to what Kate said.
Your three examples don’t work well with being.

1.*He is being famous.

We could just say
He is famous.
Being famous could be used in a sentence like
Being famous, he feels that he needs to be well-dressed all the time.


*He is being well-dressed.


To mean that he is currently dressing up, we could say
He is getting dressed up, nicely.
Being well-dressed could be used in a sentence like
Being well-dressed, he feels confident in public areas.

3.* He is being drunk.

To mean that he is almost drunk, we could say
He is getting drunk.
Being drunk could be used in a sentence like
Being drunk, he failed to behave in a way a famous person should in public.

not idiomatic okay. Yet, I think my first example is similar to this "he is being nice" meaning currently he is either nice or famous not always just now. On the other hand 2 and 3 are totally wrong if we want to say that someone has a certain feature right now. My 2 example would imply that currently clothes are being put on him by someone not that he has them on already. The same apllies to 3. Would you say that's correct and my division of adjectives makes sense?

@user203412 Being can work in “he is being nice", but the clause doesn’t mean he is nice.  It’s different from he’s nice.  The first tells us his behaviour at the moment; the second tells us his nature.

Thanks, @ishtar.  That’s true.  I’ve edited my first paragraph.

* He is being famous simply doesn’t work. At all, ever, in any context. (And that’s what the prefixed star means. It’s a notation used in linguistics to mean, “the following scrap is not a valid utterance,” usually (always?) on syntactic grounds.)
One can only use he is being X for properties X that are volitional. Thus, He is being petty (behaving otherwise is within his power to do), He is being quite clear with you (he has consciously decided to try to make his meaning plain).
Of course, that doesn’t apply when the construction is expressing a passive: He is being shaved means that someone is shaving him.

"He is being X" means that the person in question is doing something or acting in a way that makes him X. Like, "He is being nice" or "He is being hasty." You can't say, "He is being famous" because "famous" is not something you do, it's just something that may be true about you. You could say, "He is famous", but NOT "He is being famous".
Likewise you don't DO drunk. That's the end state when you drink too much.
"Well-dressed" is trickier. You could say, "He is being formal (in the way he dresses)", but not, "He is being well-dressed". Because a person doesn't really DO well-dressed, that's just the way he is when he's done. To an extent this may be a matter of convention, so if you think the distinction I am making isn't clear, just accept that that's not what fluent speakers say.
But as to your original question, adjectives that end in -ed, like "well-dressed", are used the same as "ordinary" adjectives. You can say, "He is nice" or "He is honest" or "He is well-dressed". The structure is the same in all three cases.
